# Proof of the derivative of sine

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

When proving the statement, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\cos(x)$, when $y(x)=\sin x$ there is a step that I do not fully understand.  I understand the beginning steps of $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}
=\dfrac{\sin(x)\cos(h)+\cos(x)\sin(h)-\sin(x)}{h}$$ but do not understand how this leads to the expression $$\sin(x)\left(\dfrac{\cos(h)-1}{h}\right)+\cos(x)\left(\dfrac{\sin(h)}{h}\right)$$
Any explanation for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $$\sin(x)\cos(h)-\sin(x)=\sin(x)(\cos(h)-1)$$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $h\neq 0$,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)\cos(h)+\cos(x)\sin(h)-\sin(x)}{h}
&= \frac{\sin(x)\cos(h)-\sin(x)+\cos(x)\sin(h)}{h}\\
&= \frac{\sin(x)(\cos(h)-1)+\cos(x)\sin(h)}{h}\\
&= \frac{\sin(x)(\cos(h)-1)}{h}+\frac{\cos(x)\sin(h)}{h}\\
&= \sin(x)\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}+\cos(x)\frac{\sin(h)}{h}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

factor

$$\frac {ab-b+d}{c}=\frac{b (a-1)+d}{c} $$
and isolate

$$\frac{A+B}{C}=\frac {A}{C}+\frac {B}{C} $$